jOOQ+R2DBC+MySQL stack issue: Cannot read bit(1) column
I am using the R2DBC (io.asyncer:r2dbc-mysql:1.1.3) + jOOQ (3.19.8) + MySQL (8.4.0) stack and I am having trouble setting a DDL with a default boolean value (although the issue might not be limited to just the default value).
Here is my DDL:
CREATE TABLE entity
(
    id          INT        NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    deleted_tinyint     tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    deleted_bit bit(1)     NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,

    CONSTRAINT pk_entity PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


INSERT INTO test_schema.entity (deleted_tinyint, deleted_bit)
VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT);

When I execute the query using JDBC...
private DSLContext ctx;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3310/test_schema",
                 "test",
                 "test"
        );
        ctx = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        var fetched = ctx
                .selectFrom(ENTITY)
                .fetchOne();
        log.info("{}", fetched);
    }

...I get the following result:
+----+---------------+-----------+
| id | deleted_tinyint | deleted_bit |
+----+---------------+-----------+
| 1 | 0 | false |
+----+---------------+-----------+

However, when I execute the same query using R2DBC...
    private DSLContext ctx;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = ConnectionFactories.get(
                ConnectionFactoryOptions
                        .parse("r2dbc:mysql://localhost:3310/test_schema")
                        .mutate()
                        .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.USER, "test")
                        .option(ConnectionFactoryOptions.PASSWORD, "test")
                        .build()
        );
        ctx = DSL.using(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        var fetched = Flux.from(ctx.selectFrom(ENTITY))
                .log()
                .blockFirst();
    }

... I get the following result:
+----+---------------+-----------+
| id | deleted_tinyint | deleted_bit |
+----+---------------+-----------+
| 1 | 0 | {null} |
+----+---------------+-----------+

For some reason, the column with type bit(1) is not being read in the R2DBC query. This type is preferred for representing Boolean values when working with MySQL.
I have also verified that the query being generated by jOOQ and executed by R2DBC is correct. If I take that same query and execute it using a MySQL client (e.g. MySQL Workbench), the result set includes the correct value for the deleted_bit column.
I have found a workaround using forcedTypes + tinyint(1), but it seems strange that the standard approach does not work.
I have also prepared a repository to reproduce the error: https://github.com/yirelav/jOOQ-r2dbc-example-bug-repo (I tried to make a clear readme.md there)
Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how I can fix it? Thank you in advance.
